# In analytic proofs of the hairy ball theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I don't understand this part.

> volume $f_t(A)=a_0+a_1t+...+a_nt^n$
>
> with coefficients  $a_k=\int...\int_A\sigma_k(x)dx_1...dx_n$

I understand the determinant, and I know

volume $f_t(A)=(\text{determinant of }f)*$volume $A$

if $f$ is linear transformation.

Please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [COV theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html), the volume is the integral of a determinant that depends of $t$:
$$\text{vol}(f_t(A)) = \int_A|\det Jf_t(x)|\,dx = \pm\int_A\det Jf_t(x)\,dx.$$
Developing the determinant, you can check that is a polynomial in $t$ with coefficients that are functions of $x\in\Bbb R^n$. And the integral of a finite sum is the sum of integrals.